# Docker registry with TLS - using a .pem file

Tags: docker, docker-registry

In this docker guide https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/ is the example for using **crt** and **key**:

> docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry \
>     -v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
>     -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt \
>     -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key \
>     registry:2

What should I use in case  I have a **.pem** file?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the pem file.

Comment: What I meant was, which -e option to specify? -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS...?

Comment: Is it the certificate or the private key?

Comment: The PEM file contains both.

Comment: How did that happen? Those should never be distributed to you in the same file. Have you been compromised? Did you share the private key with someone else?

Comment: I created the pem file myself.

Comment: Obviously it wants them in separate files!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separate the PEM file into two DER files (one for the private key and one for the certificate):

```
openssl x509 -in yourperm.pem -outform DER -out yourcert.crt
openssl pkey -in yourpem.pem -out yourkey.key
```

Also worth noting, the PEM file actually has the key and certificate next to each other in plan text. You can open the file and cut / paste them out to two files as well.